# Cassandra container with --net=host exits immediately

Tags: docker, cassandra

I'm trying to launch official Cassandra Docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/) as a part of [this](https://github.com/yasp-dota/yasp) project.

`docker run -d --name cassandra cassandra` succeeds at launching container.

However, I need `docker run -d --name cassandra`**`--net=host`**`cassandra` because other parts of the project work this way. If I use `--net=host`, container starts and then exits right away.

Here's what `docker ps -a` has to say:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
9f4992f06a30        cassandra:latest    "/docker-entrypoint.s"   10 seconds ago      Exited (3) 5 seconds ago                       cassandra
```

Logs say that there's an error: **`Unknown listen_address '::1 127.0.0.1'`**

Both `::1` and `127.0.0.1` are present in my `/etc/hosts` if that is relevant:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost 
::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/A44EvFbM)'s full log output for failed container and [here](http://pastebin.com/Y82R0mLe)'s `docker info` output. For comparison, [here](http://pastebin.com/67L86QCd)'s successfully running instance's logs (without `--net=host`).

Behaviour is present with and without other parts of the project, with `:3`, `:3.5`, `:3.7` and `:latest` images.

Answer (score 2):

As recommended [here](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/issues/32), overriding `CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS` works, like that:

`docker run -d --name cassandra --net=host -e CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS='127.0.0.1' cassandra`

Also, make sure that at least 4Gb RAM (swap is fine too) is available - otherwise Cassandra container will exit right away too, with different error message.

It seems that when neither device nor address are specified, Cassandra [defaults](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/938faa21697a95d7ec87dccd5750a8a80986509f/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/config/DatabaseDescriptor.java#L266) to [local address](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/938faa21697a95d7ec87dccd5750a8a80986509f/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/FBUtilities.java#L135).

Supposedly, when `hosts` file has several entries for this host (e.g. IPv4 and IPv6 ones) both are returned, which is not expected, or something like that. Supplying `127.0.0.1` manually makes sure that path never gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line ::1  on /etc/hosts will solve this problem.

Comment: That works too!
However, this line is present in `/etc/hosts` by default. I suppose it's correct, i.e. "correct `hosts` file is being misread by Cassandra", not "faulty `hosts` file prevents Cassandra from working"?